# Can I use two group_by in model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
 class << self
   def category_sort
     order(small_category_id: "asc", id: "asc")
     .group_by { |w| w.small_category.name }
   end
 end
```

That is current code and I can get hash like this.

```
 small_category1 => [data1,data2,data3]
 small_category2 => [data4,data5]
 small_category3 => [data6,data7,data8]
```

Is it possible to use two group_by in model? I am not sure how to write program. I have big_category so I would like to create hash like this.

```
 big_category1 => small_category1 => [data1,data2,data3]
               => small_category2 => [data4,data5]
 big_category2 => small_category3 => [data6,data7,data8]
```

Currently I can get the above form like this.

```
 class << self
   def category_sort
     r = order(small_category_id: "asc", id: "asc")
         .group_by { |w| [w.small_category.big_category.name, w.small_category.name] }

     hash = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = {} }
     r.each do |k, v|
       hash[k[0]][k[1]] = v
     end
   end
 end
```

Is there smarter way?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to write the same logic in 1 line to make it look cleaner:

```
class << self
   def category_sort
     order(small_category_id: "asc", id: "asc")
     .group_by { |w| [w.small_category.big_category.name, w.small_category.name] }
     .each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = {} }) {|(k,v),h| h[k.first][k.last] = v}
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try this way,

```
class << self
  def category_sort
    r = order(small_category_id: "asc", id: "asc").group_by { |w| [w.small_category.big_category.name, w.small_category.name] }.map{|key, value| {key.first => {key.last => value}}}.map(&:to_a).reduce(:concat).to_h
  end
end
```